# How to move selected data from one column to another in python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'm reading a CSV file that have two columns: continent, countries.
The cells are empty under each continents.

```
Continent    |  Countries
-----------------------------
    Asia       |   China
               |   Japan
               |   Korea
    North Am.  |   Canada
               |   U.S.
```

but I would like to merge these two columns under Continent column and have an indentation.

```
Continent
-----------
Asia 
    China
    Japan
    Korea
North America
    Canada
    U.S.
```

How can I do this using python?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's the format of the incoming data, the `two columns: continent, countries`? Is it a text file like the one you posted or is it a CSV or even a Database?

Comment: I'm using pandas dataframe to read from a CSV file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should do the trick. You don't even need to use pandas to read a CSV as Python have already a standard module for that called [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). The code outputs to another CSV called `output.csv`.

```py
import csv

continent = ''
with open('data.csv') as csv_in, open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_out:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_in)
    writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
    headers = next(reader, None) # skip the headers
    writer.writerow([headers[0]])
    for row in reader:
        prev_continent = continent
        continent = row[0].strip() or continent

        if prev_continent != continent:
          writer.writerow([continent])
        writer.writerow([f'    {row[1]}'])
```

**output.csv**

```
Continent
Asia
    China
    Japan
    Korea
North Am.
    Canada
    U.S.
```

**data.csv**

```
Continent,Countries
Asia     ,China
         ,Japan
         ,Korea
North Am.,Canada
         ,U.S.
```

Comment: How do I convert the output to a csv?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a new code that outputs to another CSV. Please take a look.